# More info form to show relationships?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a form that has text boxes that are connected to a query which is connected to a table; which has a relationship with another table which has another relationship with another table.

This is what the relationships look like:
Client>Customer>WorkOrder

There can be only 1 client, but many customers, which can have many work orders.

How do I set up this form / query to show the customer and client information of the work order? Please note to open up this more info form you need to select the work order from a subform table, then click the button. This launches the form with all the information keeping the old one still in the background because it uses a text box to detect which id is selected (the text box's name is txtWorkOrderID)

The form that pops up has a record source of a query that is made when the button is clicked, the query hosts all data from that one work order selected only; though I am not sure how to include the customer + client names in that. How would I do this?

Comment: Change the query that is the recordsource of the popup form to include the Customer & Client tables, and add the fields you require from those tables.

Comment: You can have more than 1 record source for a form?

Comment: Currently I already have a record source set for the popup form and it's a query the button makes of the 1 record you selected. How would it tell which record I selected to get the data from if it's just in the record source?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, each work order is only associated with one customer, and each customer is only assigned to one client?  i.e., Work Order #22125 is only going to be used for a job done for the customer named Maggie's Farm, and Maggie's Farm is only going to be overseen by Bob Dylan?

If so, just join the tables the same way they're joined in the Relationships form, and pull in Customer Name and Client Name from their respective tables.  You MAY need to either use a Group By query or a Select Distinct query if you're getting any Cartesian joins (joins that produce multiple duplicate records).  Your form would be based on this query, rather than a single table.

You should never edit the data in Customer or Client when you edit data in a Work Order, data doesn't flow in that direction.  If you need to edit the data, I would create the above described query and use DLookup to find the Customer and Client Names associated with a given Work Order.  Put a few textboxes on the form with Enabled = False and set their recordsource as

```
=DLookup("CustomerName", "MyQuery", "WorkOrder = '" & Me.WorkOrder & "'"
```

Then put the Work Order table as the form's record source.